# What is the mathematical and algorithm way to represent "all possible configuration"?

Tags: algorithms

I have two rigid 3D objects, where one of the object, say A, slide/glide on the other object, say B. Now what I want to do is to find all possible valid configuration/pose of A on B. How can I say this using math formula? After that, how can I write that in algorithmic way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a model/sketch/picture to illustrate the problem? Only touching configurations are valid? What these objects are used for? Is anything [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/lecture/Chap3-Config-Space_howie.pdf) connected to your problem?

Comment: @Evil I'm trying to model interaction between 2 bones. Yes, only touching configurations are valid. You can assume the object A has 6 DoF. Yes, they might be related to the term I'm looking for, I will read in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: This all sounds rather vague, so it's hard for me to tell what kind of answers you are looking for.  "How can I say this.." -- say what?  What do you want to use your math formula for?  What quantities are you trying to relate?  How will you evaluate possible answers?  What does it mean to "write that in an algorithmic way"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @D.W. I think mention what I want to achieve in the first and second sentences.